# Is it possible to use Android scripts created with ASE as typical application for Android (e.g. written in Java)?

Tags: android, scripting, ase

I am very very new to Android. I was encouraged to take a closer look at Android when I heard about possbility to write applications on Android in scripting languages like Python. This sounds great and in fact works great.

I did some experiments and everything looks very interesting. I have noticed that I can either write my scripts on Android or create script file on my computer and then copy them to Android ase/scripts folder. This is somehow different (as far as I know) from process of creating application for Android in Java (when you create code, compile it to .apk and install on Android).

To be more specific I want to know:

1. what are limitations (if any) of script-based applications on Android?
2. is it possible to ship apps written in scripitng languages to Android Market and let other users install them without requirement to install ASE?
3. is there some way to create more complicated, multi-file projects in scripting languages on Android?

Thanks for any hints. Also please feel free to correct me if I made any error or wrong assumption in my question - as I wrote, I am very new to Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what are limitations (if any) of
>   script-based applications on Android?

I would flip the question around. Scripts can only execute what is native to their language plus the things exposed by the [Android facade](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference). As such, you are not creating full user interfaces and the like -- at most, you have access to some pre-packaged dialogs (e.g., `getPassword()`). So, for scripting purposes, ASE is very slick, but you are not creating applications, IMHO.

> is it possible to ship apps written in
>   scripitng languages to Android Market
>   and let other users install them
>   without requirement to install ASE?

Not presently. It is something that is being worked on.

> is there some way to create more
>   complicated, multi-file projects in
>   scripting languages on Android?

Ummmm...you could try whatever sort of "include" construct there is in your language of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not personally done so, it appears possible to compile your python scripts into an .apk. Take a peek at the instructions for sharing scripts on the [Android-Scripting Wiki][1]

[1]: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/SharingScripts"Android Scripting Wiki"